# Какой MySQL запрос быстрее?

Tags: mysql

из двух таблиц, имеющих одинаковое количество записей, с общим полем необходимо выбрать данные (по строчке из таблицы). как быстрее это сделать: двумя запросами или одним с join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один запрос с join лучше двух простых.

Comment: краткий и чёткий ответ по делу, спасибо.

Comment: услышать бы еще объяснение, почему так происходит

Comment: потому что сервер будет данные готовить за один раз. То есть, в данном случае один запрос будет не медленее, чем два отдельных.

два отдельных запроса - это два раза получение запроса, разбор его, формирование ответа. Один запрос, но побольше - это уже одно получение, один разбор (может чуточку длинее, но все равно быстрее чем два отдельных).

Answer (score 0):

Откройте СУБД (тот же phpmyadmin) выполните оба запроса и посмотрите на время выполнения.

В вашем случае скорее запрос с join будет быстрее.

Я встречал сложные запросы с несколькими join-ами которые выполнялись несколько секунд. После переписывания в несколько раздельных запросов время выполнения сокращалось до меньше секунды.